# get outlook mailitem for message taken from outlook table

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-2007, outlook-2010

How can I get a reference to the MailItem for a message taken from an Outlook table? If I generate a table which contains rows with messages and tell it to add the column with messages' EntryID, the EntryID is not the same one as the one I can see for the same message when I simply loop through the folder's Items list.

Is there any other way to get the message?

I'm using Outlook 2007 and 2010. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If your store is an Exchange mailbox, then the table will return short-term entry IDs for the `PR_ENTRYID` property. These entry IDs are valid for the current session, but should not be persisted. To force the table to return long-term IDs, request the `PR_LONGTERM_ENTRYID_FROM_TABLE` (`0x66700102`) property instead; however, be careful that this property will be absent for PST providers.

Reference: [MAPI Tables](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/mapitable.htm#mapitables) by Dmitry Streblechenko