# Attempting to get DASL property value from the Outlook table inbox

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2010, outlook-redemption

I'm attempting to read the DASL value PR_LONGTERM_ENTRYID_FROM_TABLE 0x66700102 mentioned in this thread - 
[get outlook mailitem for message taken from outlook table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848813/get-outlook-mailitem-for-message-taken-from-outlook-table)

The issue I'm having is with the following line in the code below from the full example below-

```
string ltEntryid = (string)nextRow["http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x66700102".ToString()];
```

It throws an exception "Cannot convert type 'byte[]' to 'string'"

I might be going about this the wrong way so I'm looking for some advice. I can read all the other tables rows fine (Example- "EntryID(short term), MessageClass, Unread, SenderEmailType).

```
const string unReadfilter = "[UnRead] = true";
Outlook.Table table = folder.GetTable(unReadfilter, Outlook.OlTableContents.olUserItems);

// Remove the default column set.
table.Columns.RemoveAll();

// Add columns to the table
table.Columns.Add("Unread");
table.Columns.Add("EntryID");
table.Columns.Add("MessageClass");
table.Columns.Add("SenderEmailType");
table.Columns.Add("SenderEmailAddress");
// PR_LONGTERM_ENTRYID_FROM_TABLE
table.Columns.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x66700102".ToString());
// sort table
table.Sort("Unread", true);

while (!table.EndOfTable)
{
  Outlook.Row nextRow = table.GetNextRow();
  bool unRead = (bool)nextRow["Unread"];
  Debug.WriteLine(unRead);
  string msgClass = (string)nextRow["MessageClass"];
  Debug.WriteLine(msgClass);
  string eId = (string)nextRow["EntryID"];
  Debug.WriteLine(eId);
  string sEaddr = (string)nextRow["SenderEmailAddress"];
  Debug.WriteLine(sEaddr);
  string sEtype = (string)nextRow["SenderEmailType"];
  Debug.WriteLine(sEtype);

  // PR_LONGTERM_ENTRYID_FROM_TABLE ***Exception with the following line***
  string ltEntryid = (string)nextRow["http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x66700102".ToString()];

  Debug.WriteLine(ltEntryid);

  if (msgClass.Equals("IPM.Note"))
    {
    //write to string list
    dailyMiInboxList.Add(unRead.ToString());
    dailyMiInboxList.Add(msgClass);
    dailyMiInboxList.Add(eId);
    dailyMiInboxList.Add(sEaddr);
    dailyMiInboxList.Add(sEtype);
    dailyMiInboxList.Add(sEaddr);
    dailyMiInboxList.Add(ltEntryid);     
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured this out with Dmitry's help.

First when adding this dasl property to the table -

```
// PR_LONGTERM_ENTRYID_FROM_TABLE
table.Columns.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x66700102".ToString());
```

I should've not included the tostring so it should be written as follows-

```
  table.Columns.Add(@"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x66700102");
```

Next in the While loop, to convert the PT_BINARY property from an array of bytes use this to convert the row-

```
string PR_LONGTERM_ENTRYID_FROM_TABLE = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x66700102";
string ltEntryId = (string)nextRow.BinaryToString(PR_LONGTERM_ENTRYID_FROM_TABLE);
Debug.Print(ltEntryId);
```

[This link was very helpful](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb226714(v=office.12).aspx)

In particular these comments-
**• The value returned for a given column representing a binary (PT_BINARY) value depends on whether a built-in property name or a schema name was used to specify the Column. For explicit built-in property names (such as EntryID), the Row(Column) value is returned as a string. For property names referencing a namespace that represent a PT_BINARY property, the Row(Column) value is returned as a byte array. Use Row.BinaryToString to convert the byte array to a string.**

Answer (score 2):

PT_BINARY property is returned as an array of byte, but you are casting it to a string. If you want to convert it to a hex string, use `MAPIFolder.PropertyAccessor.BinaryToString()`.